# How do I add Data.Bits to Data.Modular, automatically?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, ghc

I need to `xor` a couple of mod numbers (from Data.Modular)....

```
let x = 4 :: Integer `Mod` 10
    y = 6 :: Integer `Mod` 10

print $ x `xor` y
```

....but, this doesn't work, because `Mod x y` is not an instance of Data.Bits.

I can, or course, convert the values to Integers, xor it, and convert back.  Or, I could even make `Mod x y` an instance of Bits by hand by writing all the class functions, but this is all ugly boilerplate code, which should be automated.  The StandaloneDeriving extension would be the way to achieve this, but it doesn't seem to work....

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeOperators, TypeSysonymInstances, FlexibleInstances, StandaloneDeriving #-}

import Data.Bits
import Data.Modular
import GHC.TypeLits

deriving instance Bits (Int `Mod` 10)
```

yields

"Can't make a derived instance of 'Bits (Mod Int 10)': The data constructors of 'Mod' are not all in scope so you cannot derive an instance for it"

I am not married to StandaloneDeriving, I just would like any solution that gives my xor'able modular numbers (minus a bunch of boilerplate)....

Comment: Note that doing this just by `xor`ring the underlying bits doesn't work: ``9 `xor` 4`` is `13`.  This sort of thing is why the constructor for `Mod` is hidden, and why the derived instance wouldn't work.

Comment: Also if the modulus is not a power of 2 then the result will depend on which representative Integer you choose, and if you choose the smallest nonnegative representative then this operation will not be associative (unlike xor), because the "convert back" operation loses information. This is really a strange operation; what are you using it for, out of curiosity?

Comment: @AntalS-Z- D'oh, you are correct!  Your comment resonated with me, indicating that I was doing something wrong.  I looked back at the algorithm, and in fact, I had it wrong....  I need to convert my mod values to Integers, and output an Integer....  If you turn your comment into an answer, I would be happy to award you the credit....

Comment: @jamshidh: Done (with a little more detail, because I have a natural tendency to be verbose…).  Interestingly, though, I didn't get notified from your ping, so I'm glad I saw it :-)  Perhaps it's treating the trailing `-` as part of the username it's looking for?

Comment: @AntalS-Z thanks for letting me know about the "-"....  I've probably done this many times in the past too, and never realized that my messages weren't getting though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't implement `xor` for modular numbers just by xorring the underlying bits; you'll get out-of-range numbers.  For example:

```
ghci> 9 `xor` 4 :: Integer
13
```

This is what the derived instance would do, which means it wouldn't work anyway.  This sort of thing is why the constructor for `Mod` is hidden: so that the "is less than `n`" invariant can be maintained via smart constructors.

But the situation here is worse: *modular numbers really **aren't** a sensible instance of `Bits`!*  In general, in a case like this, the code you write instead of automatic type class instantiations just uses a bunch of lifting functions such as

```
mapMod :: (KnownNat n, Integral j) => (i -> j) -> i `Mod` n -> j `Mod` n
mapMod f = toMod . f . unMod

liftMod2 :: (KnownNat n, Integral k)
         => (i -> j -> k) -> i `Mod` n -> j `Mod` n -> k `Mod` n
liftMod2 f x y = toMod $ f (unMod x) (unMod y)
```

and then implementing a whole bunch of methods as `(.&.) = liftMod2 (.&.)` and so on (including `xor = liftMod2 xor`).

Unfortunately, that produces a whole bunch of issues.  Here's a not-necessarily exhaustive list.  Given an instance `` Bits (i `Mod` n) ``:

1. `bitSizeMaybe` doesn't really have a great definition.  It probably should be the number of bits it takes to represent `n-1`, but consider `n = 10`: then we'll claim to have a 4-bit number, but that seems like a claim there are 16 possible numbers mod 10!  Perhaps we should claim to be a log₂ 10 = 3.32…-bit number?  (This lack of an integral bit size is arguably the root of the problem.)
2. `bit` needs to be modulus-aware, so it can't just be lifted: consider `n = 10`, again, where `bit 3 == 8` but `bit 4 == 0`.  This would be OK, but…
3. `setBit` gets weird.  Again, consider `n = 10`, and `3 = 0b0011`.  Then `setBit 3 3` can't just compute `0b1011 = 11`; it instead has to work out to `0b0001 = 1`, which has even *fewer* bits set.  That last bit isn't fully there!
4. `complement` is similarly wonky: in four bits, we have `complement 3 = complement 0b0011 = 0b1100 = 12`.  So when working mod 10, should `complement 3 = 2`, so that `complement 0b0011 = 0b0010`?  Ugh.
5. [As Reid Barton said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910433/how-do-i-add-data-bits-to-data-modular-automatically#comment47943600_29910433), the resulting `xor` operation isn't associative.  Given `xorM = liftMod2 xor`, we have

   ```
   ghci> (9 `xorM` 4) `xorM` 3 :: Integer `Mod` 10
   0
   ghci> 9 `xorM` (4 `xorM` 3) :: Integer `Mod` 10
   4
   ```

   Bitwise or similarly breaks (although bitwise and is fine, I believe).  This is because bitwise (x)or can produce larger numbers, whose remainders are then taken, and this remainder-taking is not associative over bitwise operations.

The only case where this instance *does* make sense, as (once again) [mentioned by Reid Barton in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910433/how-do-i-add-data-bits-to-data-modular-automatically#comment47943600_29910433), is when `n` is a power of 2.  Then you would essentially have a mod-based encoding of a computer-style binary number, just of a potentially different size (128-bit? 256-bit? 1024-bit?), the simple liftings would work fine, and the weird behavior would go away, because your type would really have a whole number of bits.